# How can i hide unselected options items on nested select in angular material multi select?

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, nested-select

I need a help about angular material select-boxes.
When i select items in first tab i must to view in two nested one single and one multi-select box on other tab. Then i must to view selected combinations by adding them in List or table.

Here is code link about my problem: [code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhkmim)

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get what you want to achive because I do not understand your English :-/ Can you describe it in a better, more precise way?

Comment: thank you very much. I solve my problem.